# Comment system Displays multiple posts of a single post (php mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to implement a comment system, but it returns the post as many times the comment of that post exists.

Please help me with the code to solve out this.
Thank you.

The sample I have is like:

```
    <?php

include('connect.php');

?>

<form method="post">

Subject<br>
<input type="text" name="subject"><br><br>
Message<br>
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="poster" value="Post">

</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['poster'])) {
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $message=$_POST['text'];

    $post=mysql_query("insert into comment (titles, message) values ('$subject', '$message')");
    if ($post) {
        echo "Data got";
    }else{
        echo "Failed";
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}

$select=mysql_query("SELECT comment.id, comment.titles, comment.message, replies.id, replies.idno, replies.subject, replies.textfile from comment left JOIN replies ON comment.id=replies.id ;");


while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)) {

    echo "<b>".$row['titles']."</b><br>";
    echo $row['message']."<br>";
    echo "<a href=\"edit.php?id=$row[id]\">Reply</a><br>";
    echo "<font color='green'><ul>".$row['textfile']."</ul></font><br><br>";

}

?>
```

But it returns:

[image: Result]

Thank you.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0):

your code seem was wrong in this line:

```
$select=mysql_query("SELECT comment.id, comment.titles, comment.message, replies.id, replies.idno, replies.subject, replies.textfile from comment left JOIN replies ON comment.id=replies.id ;");
```

on left join , comment.id must compare with other replies table fields like replies.commentid for example the end of your query must be like this:

```
ON comment.id=replies.commentid;");
```

Comment: can you explain field name in two tables (comment and replies).

Comment: I have it as follows:  Comment=> id, titles, message  and replies=> idno, subject, textfile, id(from comment).   The comment table is the one that gets the post and the replies table is the one tat gets the replies to the comment/ post. id and idno takes int(20), titles and subject varchar(255) and the rest take text.  Help please, thank you.

Comment: I wish to have the replies nested in their post. that's no repeat of the post for the reply.

Comment: Please I need more help!